# Why does the F# compiler not create a tail call for this function?

Tags: f#, tail-recursion, tail-call-optimization, fixpoint-combinators, f#-3.1

I'm having trouble with the fixed point combinator in F#:

```ml
let rec fix f a = f (fix f) a

fix (fun body num -> 
    if num = 1000000 
    then System.Console.WriteLine "Done!" 
    else body (num + 1)
) 0
```

(This code is just to demonstrate the problem, it was written specifically so that the generated IL code is easy to read.)

This code - when compiled with optimizations and tailcalls enabled - causes a `StackOverflowException`. I looked at the IL code and could trace the problem to the lambda inside the call to `fix`:

```
.method assembly static void f@1 (class FSharpFunc`2<int32, class Unit> body,int32 num)
{
ldarg.1
ldc.i4 1000000
bne.un.s IL_0014

ldstr "Done!"
call void Console::WriteLine(string)
ret

IL_0014: ldarg.0 // Load the 'body' function onto the stack.
ldarg.1 // Load num onto the stack.
ldc.i4.1
add

// Invoke the 'body' function with num+1 as argument.
callvirt instance !1 class FSharpFunc`2<int32, class Unit>::Invoke(!0)
// Throw away the unit result.
pop
ret
}
```

(I modified the code a little so it is easier to read.)

The reason for the `StackOverflowException` is that the call to `body` is no tail call (the `callvirt` instruction at the bottom). And the reason for that is because the compiler created a call to the lambda that actually returns `Unit`!

So in C# terms: Body is `Func<Int32,Unit>` when it really should be `Action<Int32>`. Since the call returns something that has to be discarded, it cannot be a tailcall. Also note that the method `f@1` is compiled as `void`, not `Unit`, that's the reason the result from the call to the argument has to be discarded.

Is this actually intended or can I do something about it?
The way the compiler treats this lambda makes the fixed point combinator useless for all purposes I intended to use it.

---

I just want to add that as long as you return something as a result, it works fine. Only functions that return nothing do not work as expected.

This works:

```ml
let rec fix f a = f (fix f) a

fix (fun body num ->
    if num = 1000000
    then System.Console.WriteLine "Done!"; 0
    else body (num + 1)
) 0
|> ignore
```

And this is now the code generated for the lambda:

```
.method assembly static int32 f@11 (class FSharpFunc`2<int32, int32> body, int32 num)
{
ldarg.1
ldc.i4 1000000
bne.un.s IL_0015

ldstr "Done!"
call void Console::WriteLine(string)
ldc.i4.0
ret

IL_0015: ldarg.0
ldarg.1
ldc.i4.1
add
tail.
callvirt instance !1 class FSharpFunc`2<int32, int32>::Invoke(!0)
ret
}
```

Now there is a tailcall. And everything works fine.

---

The IL code for `fix` (for discussion in comments):

```
.method public static !!b fix<a, b> (class FSharpFunc`2<class FSharpFunc`2<!!a, !!b>, class FSharpFunc`2<!!a, !!b>> f, !!a a) 
{    
    ldarg.0
    ldarg.0
    newobj instance void class Program/fix@11<!!a, !!b>::.ctor(class FSharpFunc`2<class FSharpFunc`2<!0, !1>, class FSharpFunc`2<!0, !1>>)
    ldarg.1
    tail.
    call !!0 class FSharpFunc`2<class FSharpFunc`2<!!a, !!b>, !!a>::InvokeFast<!!b>(class FSharpFunc`2<!0, class FSharpFunc`2<!1, !!0>>, !0, !1)
    ret
}
```

So it would appear to me that the `(fix f)` inside the definition of fix is not a recursive call that happens at this time, but merely a reference to `fix` itself that - along with the argument `f` - gets stored away into a closure called `Program/fix@11` and is passed to the lambda as an argument which then actually calls `fix` via this closure.

Otherwise this would be infinite recursion from the beginning and `fix` would be useless.

I'm using F# version 3.1.2, F# Interactive version 12.0.30815.0

---

## Please:

I am not interested in alternate solutions. I just want to know why the compiler returns a `Unit` that needs to be thrown away when the lambda does not produce a result.

Comment: if you look at `fix` you will see that the recursive call of `fix` is not in *tail-call* position (as it is followed by `f`) ... so no surprise here - btw: it's not the *lambda*  that messes up the fixpointcombinator - it's the definition of `fix` itself

Comment: what you can do is (although the theory behind `fix` is nice) not to use `fix` but use the given optimized functions like `Seq.iter` or `List.iter` in this case (or even just use a `for` loop) - recursion is nice and you should understand it but after you understand it you should use common abstractions instead)

Comment: @CarstenKönig, there is no recursive call in ``fix``, it's a partial function application passed to ``f``. The call happens in the lambda ``f``. You can check the IL code for ``fix`` if you don't believe me ;) I added another example that work fine with the same ``fix`` function.

Comment: @CarstenKönig, I added the IL code of fix to show that this is not a recursive call, just a indirect recursive call.

Comment: @CarstenKönig, sorry, but you are mixing things up. The ``tail`` in ``fix`` is preceding the call to ``f``. The recursive call to ``fix`` (and I apologise, of course it's a recursive call) is stored away inside a closure (the argument ``body`` of the lambda) and called inside the lambda. And this is not a tailcall in the first case, but it is a tailcall in the second case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75597/discussion-between-nikon-the-third-and-carsten-konig).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In fact, you have already answered your own question. Quoting the comment from the source code,

```
// Throw away the unit result
```

is the pending operation **after** the call, preventing the compiler from using a tail call here.

There's a great blog post by Keith Battocchi, ["Tail calls in F#"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2011/07/08/tail-calls-in-fsharp.aspx) (scroll to section "Limitations / Calling function values returning unit") which discovers a lot of details.

In two words:
Normally, F# functions `… -> unit` are compiled to .NET methods returning `void`.
However, *functions treated as values* (e.g., those passed as arguments to higher-order functions) are stored in objects of type `('a->'b)` so they actually return `Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit`, not `void`.
The compiler needs to **pop the dummy `unit` value** off of the stack before returning.
Therefore, there *is* a pending operation *after* the recursive call, and therefore the compiler can't optimize it to a tail call.

Good news:

> Note that this issue only arises when using first-class functions as values.  Calling normal .NET methods **which return void** doesn’t present this problem, because there is no return value to pop off of the stack.

Comment: Thank you for the linkt to the blog post!

Answer (score 3):

To tail call optimize your code, the compiler must tail call optimize `fix`. With higher-order function in fix, the compiler is confused.

If you want a tail-recursive `fix`, try to define it differently:

```
let rec iter p f x =
  if p x then x
  else iter p f (f x)

iter ((=) 100000000) ((+) 1) 0
```

Interesting fact: Your `fix` would not stack overflow in Haskell because of how Haskell evaluates expressions: Haskell uses graph reduction, which is different from using call stacks.

```
let fix f = f (fix f)
fix (\f x -> if x == 100000000 then -1 else f (x + 1)) 0
```

Speaking of your second example, the .NET just-in-time might be able to optimize tail calls at runtime. Since it's a optimization, it depends on how smart the runtime is: Having return value or not might stump the JIT optimizer.
For example, Mono on my machine didn't optimize your second example.

See also: [Generate tail call opcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15864670/generate-tail-call-opcode)

Comment: I added another example that works fine (you just have to return a result so that the compiler can't compile the lambda as a ``void`` function).

Comment: @CarstenKönig, I actually use FSharpx, and this is how ``fix`` is defined. I just checked the IL of the new example: ``tail. callvirt instance !1 class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<int32, int32>::Invoke(!0)``. So this is exactly how I expected the other one to work as well.

Comment: I suspect the .NET just-in-time can optimize tail calls. It didn't happen in my Mono, but it might happen in .NET on Windows.

Comment: @Ming-Tang Mono (AFAIK) right now will ignore the IL code for tail-calls. If the fsharp compiler is smart enough to translate the recursion into a loop you are fine - if not you will get stack-overflows. I think this will not change till the .net-core code got merged into Mono which might happen soonish